# Grub error occured?

Tags: grub2, grub, grub-legacy

I just upgraded my parrot OS using the command line. And when I restarted the pc this error occurred : *Symbol ‘grub disk native sectors’ not found*.  I have tried `set` command to solve this issue but didn’t work. When I start it in the `normal` mode , same error occurs … How to solve it?. Thanks in advance.